# Implementation of Internal mailbox using sails.js

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I would like to implement an internal mailbox in my web application. I tried to find something out myself but I am not sure if it is what do I need. I want to allow my users to send messages among themselves but this is not a kind of chat, it should be an internal mailbox, persisted to database. Could you give me some advises or links to get started with my problem?

thanks

Comment: That's a way to broad question - you are asking for the entire implementation! Could you update your question with what you have done until now and what the problems are you can not solve on your own.

Comment: Please dont just ask SO to do the work for you..  http://whathaveyoutried.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to add model something like this:

```
//Message.js

module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    fromUser:'integer',
    toUser:'integer',
    title:'string',
    body:'string',
    haveReaded:'boolean'
  }

};
```

And add all functionality what you need. For example, create new message:

```
var msg = {
    fromUser: %USER_ID%,
    toUser: %TO_USER_ID%,
    title: "Hi man!",
    body: "How are you doing?",
    haveReaded: false
}

Message.create(msg).done(function(err, msg){
    if(err) return console.log("Message sending error");
    console.log("Message send");
});
```

Checking for new messages:

```
Message.find().where({ toUser: : %USER_ID% })
.where({ haveReaded: false })
.exec(function(err, messages) {
    if(messages.length > 0){
        console.log("User have " + messages.length + " new messages");
    }else{
        console.log("No new messages");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How can i know one user is online/offline ie users status is online/offline ? Is there any way to find that as i need to show the status of the user?

Comment: You can add "lastSeen" property to User model with "date" type. You have to update this property (lastSeen = currentTime + 5min) whenever user doing some action (loading page, call some API, looking web page). 5min - it's timeout time. For checking is user online you have compare lastSeen property with current time. If lastSeen is less than current time than it's means that user at least 5 min not online.

Comment: ya got it..Thanks..i have added lastLogin as field in my model...for displaying the status..

Comment: Is there any way to track user online/offline system status using websockets rather than using a field lastSeen?

Comment: Yes, you can use websockets. But in any case you have to use lastSeen. You can update this field by command send using socket. This is the easiest way

Comment: Thanks for your reply..Did u happen to get any link to track user online offline status using websockets? If so can u post it here?